# sound played by headphones contain much noise, where the sound of printscreen screen capture works perfect

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I've a laptop (Vaio VPCM13M1E) with ubuntu 14.04 installed. The sound of my laptop speakers works fine, but the sound of my headphones while playing a medium or through internet contains much noise. Although when I capture a screen (Ctrl + PrtSc) the sound is perfect.

Also when I do the `Speaker Testing for Headphones` in `System Settings` it is all good

So how can I make sure the audio from files or internet is played according the right settings?

`alsa_utils` version is `1.0.27.2` and 
`aplay -l` gives

```
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` shows

```
  00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: IBM Device 9075
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
        Memory at feb00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

  00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
```

And `cat /proc/asound/cards` shows:

```
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xfeb000000 irq 41
```

Following [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/195605) bug report, I've added the following lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-card-0 index=0
options snd-hda-intel model=vaio
```

Rebooted and applied `sudo alsa force-reload`, but the sound of mediums and through internet keeps containing noise. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used [this troubleshooting page](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/sound/sound_troubleshooting.htm) for sound, which gives a nice flowchart to rule things out.

[image: flowchart]

For me the speaker test `speaker-test -c2 -t wav` was successful, so I thought it had to do the with the output (ALSA, Pulseaudio, oss, Jack), which I could change while playing a song on repeat using qmmp (`sudo apt-get install qmmp`), but the real solution for playing was that the plug of my headphones was TOO DEEP in the jack for Firefox, YouTube, Mplayer where the speaker test was working fine no matter how deep the headphones were plugged in.